# How to use the Attribute API inside a concern in a Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport-concern

I have a simple generic model rails that looks like this:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :foo, :integer
  include AConcern
end
```

And it include a basic concern that looks like this…

```
module AConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

The model also has an attribute called :foo using the attribute api from below:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

The attribute relates to the the concern, so every time I want to use the concern, in each model I have to define the attribute and then include the concern.

If I put the attribute declration inside the concern like this:

```
module AConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  attribute :foo, :integer
end
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `attribute' for AConcern:Module
```

How do I use the attribute definition in the concern so I don’t have to declare it in every model before including the concern? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ActiveSupport::Concern` included hook to handle this e.g.

```
module AConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do 
    attribute :foo, :integer
  end
end
```

Then

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  include AConcern
end
```

The problem you are experiencing right now is that `attribute` is being called in the context of your `Module` but that module does not have access to that method (hence `NoMethodError`).

The `included` hook is run when you call `include` and the hook is run in the context of the including `Object` ( `Thing` in this case). `Thing` does have the `attribute` method and thus everything works as expected.

`included` block from `ActiveSupport::Concern` is essentially the same as (in pure ruby)

```
module AConcern
  def self.included(base) 
    base.class_eval { attribute :foo, :integer } 
  end 
end
```